# Regex Performance Python

Tags: python, regex, optimization

I am writing a Python script that is passing over upwards of 20GB of news article data. For every single line that is a "date" (once every 100 lines or so), I need to check if the title of that article is financial. The title is in the form:

```
SOME BIG NEWS HAPPENED TO CISCO
```

My code loops through every company name in the S&P 500 (which I have cached in a `set`), and tries to see if the title matches.

```
line = "SOME BIG NEWS HAPPENED TO CISCO"
for company in company_names:
    pattern = re.compile("(\\b" + company_name + "\\b)", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        do_something()
```

I copied over a mere 100,000 lines to a separate file to test my program, and it took 347 seconds. At this rate, it won't get through all of my data for upwards of a week.

I am trying to figure out how it could possibly take so long to loop through my file. Is the problem that `Python` is unable to cache all of the compiled DFA's and needs to instead construct  ~500 each time I encounter a new article?

Or is there another problem with my current regular expression that would cause such a long execution time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might try keeping a set of pre-compiled regex vs re-compiling them all 500 times.

Comment: Thanks @dawg, I actually was thinking the same thing right after posting. I am about to test.

Comment: You might not try using regex at all and instead  `company_name in line`. It should be a lot faster, but the same complexity.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: If the line is `I googled Trump and look what I found!`, I do not want it to return `True` for `company_name in line`

Comment: Consider creating a single regex containing all your search term using alternation: \b(CISCO|APPLE|FACEBOOK)\b etc. This way all the looping to match each line happens in C.

Comment: That task looks suspiciously close to `for company in company_names: if company in ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, line.lower())).split(): do_something()`.

Comment: @JackRyan I am missing something obvious, I can only surmise, but how would that be different that a `\bTrump\b` regex?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Well, it would improperly match something like `Two-Year-Old Plays Trumpet` while the regex wouldn't.

Comment: Add spaces then. You sacrifice something on the generality of the word-boundary, sure

Comment: But what about if it occurs at the beginning or the end of the line? I need the `\b` to distinguish a whole word.

Comment: Start with a first pass using `" "+company_name` and see if that gets you down to a reasonable time. Then, do a second pass on a much smaller dataset with regex.

Comment: @kindall I believe the `dict` of precompiled regex will perform similarly, as it is only the ramp-up time of compiling the 500 initially. It could definitely save a constant factor though, and I could use all the speedup I can get at this point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try holding pre compiled patterns in a dict. Something like:

```
companies=('Cisco', 'Apple', 'IBM', 'GE')
patterns={co:re.compile("(\\b" + co + "\\b)", flags=re.IGNORECASE) for co in companies}
line = "SOME BIG NEWS HAPPENED TO CISCO"
for co, pat in patterns.items():
    if re.search(pat, line):
        print "'{}' found in: '{}'".format(co, line)
```

Or, you might try Python's string methods:

```
words=line.lower().split()      
for co in [e.lower() for e in companies]:
    if co in words:
       print "'{}' found in: '{}'".format(co, line)
```

Note that doing a `[e.strip(',.!:;') for e in line.lower().split()]` on the line is nearly equivalent to using word boundaries and case insensitive in a regex. (Or use TigerhawkT3's `''.join(filter(str.isalpha, line.lower())).split(): do_something()`)

You can also use a [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) to get common words:

```
>>> line2="Apple acquires Cisco: Generally a good thing"
>>> set(e.lower() for e in companies) & set(e.strip(',.!:;') for e in line2.lower().split())
set(['cisco', 'apple'])
```

Comment: `.lower().split()` isn't equivalent. Any company names in the headline will have to be an exact match, meaning that leading or trailing punctuation (e.g. `Difficulties at companyname, layoffs expected`) will break it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes -- correct -- let me fix that. You pick up on that regularly!

Comment: Correction on my snippet: that'll remove the spaces. Oops. `''.join(c for c in line.lower() if not c.strip() or c.isalpha()).split(): do_something()` is probably better.

Comment: Thanks @dawg, I ended up going with the `dict` comprehension and the speedup is very substantial.